# Streaming wav file to Ipad and Firefox with <audio>

Tags: c#, ipad, html, audio, filestream

I´m trying to play wav files with the audio element. This works great when I reference the file directly BUT when I try to stream it via a c# FileStream it stops working.
The code below work perfect for Chrome and Opera on PC but I am trying to get it to work on Ipad and Firefox.
I am using .net framwork 2.0
I have to use wav.

```
<audio id="audio" src="www.acme.com/streamer.aspx?music=test.wav" controls preload="auto"></audio> Not working
<audio id="audio" src="test.wav" controls preload="auto"></audio> Working
```

The stream function below:

```
string wavFileName = test.wav;
FileStream soundStream;
long FileSize;


soundStream = new FileStream(@"\\netshare\" + wavfileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 256);
FileSize = soundStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
int count = 0;
int offset = 0;
while ((count = soundStream.Read(Buffer, offset,
Buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(Buffer, offset, count);
}
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "audio/wave");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + wavfileName);
Response.ContentType = "audio/wave";
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
if (soundStream != null)
{
    soundStream.Close();
}

Response.End();
```

(btw, this is my first post, hope i did not break any rules)

Answer (score 2):

The code seems fine. I think you need to make sure that the wav file is in the write PCM format. Some browsers have issues playing certain PCMs. I found out that just because a browse(html5)) supports a wav file does not mean it will actually play all wav type.

You might also want to flush the Response.